# How to toggle the sidebar menu for every browser size?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to get the `menu-toggle` button to show and hide the sidebar in this [template](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/simple-sidebar.html) for every browser size and not only if it's smaller than 767px? Currently the button only shows up if the browser window is smaller than 767px.

This is the CSS of it:
- http://startbootstrap.com/templates/css/simple-sidebar.css

I tried to change the `display` from `none` to `inline-block`, but now the menu doens't toggle anymore:

```
#menu-toggle {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is in the @media query. Near the bottom of the stylesheet, you'll notice

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
    ...
}
```

Whatever styles you want applied universally, just remove them from this block, and place them in the body of your stylesheet instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your css (above @media query) change:

```
#menu-toggle {
 display: none;
}
```

to:

```
#menu-toggle {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but now the menu is not sliding out anymore, it just stays where it is. Any ideas?

Comment: probably menu also activates under 767px. you should check rest of your code (jquery or css)